# Remove a class clicking a button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I set class `active` when i click on a `div`.

```js
 const setActive = () => {
    setActiveColor("active");
  };
```

I want to delete this class when i click on `click here to deselect color` button from `App` component. How to do this?

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-elbakyan-hi12l?file=/src/App.js:541-569

Answer (score 0):

```
const setActive = (flag) => {
  setActiveColor(flag ? "active": "");
};
```

And you can set active as:

```
setActive(true);
```

or inactive as:

```
setActive(false);
```

Comment: Probably this can be better, but i think you understand the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a state variable in your class and based on your clicks you can change that variable to add or remove class

```
class Demo{
  constructor(){
    this.state={addClass:true}
  }
  render(){ 
    return({
        this.state.addClass?<div className="some-class">With class</div>
       :<div>Without class</div>
    })
  }
}

// Or
 class Demo{
  constructor(){
    this.state={addClass:true}
  }
  render(){ 
    return(
        <div className={this.state.addClass?"some-name":null}>Lorem</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to move activeStateColor to the parent.

Then when you click on the setActive you pass the key as reference.

[image: Edit modest-einstein-n4pr2]

```
export const Shape = ({ text, k, active, setActiveColor }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ visible: false });

  const showModal = k => {
    setState({
      visible: true
    });
    setActiveColor(k);
  };

  const handleOk = e => {
    console.log(e);
    setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  const handleCancel = e => {
    setActiveColor("");

    console.log(e);
    setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };
  const setActive = k => {
    setActiveColor(k);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={() => showModal(k)}>
          Open Modal
        </Button>
        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          visible={state.visible}
          onOk={handleOk}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
        >
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
          <p>Some contents...</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div
          k={k}
          className={active === k ? "active" : ""}
          style={{ border: "1px solid" }}
          onClick={() => setActive(k)}
        > 
          {text}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```