# accomplish the same code's result from jquery to React js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

hi dears I am just looking to achieve the same result with React js

I know my request may be silly but I am still learning to connect pattern between js and react js in a practical project

here is the sandbox [Neumorphism Button](https://codepen.io/sebastian-piskaty/pen/dyPWwLL)

```
  $(".m_button").click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass("active");
  });
```

Comment: Lets assume you have a component called `MButton`. In `MButton` you could keep track of a state variable (using `useState` for a function component or `this.setState` for a class component) which determines whether the button is active or not i.e. `const [active, setActive] = useState(false);`. A click handler can be created to update the state i.e. `const toggleActive = () => setActive(current => !current);` This click handler can then be applied to the rendered button `<button onClick={toggleActive} />`.

Comment: The state can be used to apply conditional styles `<button className={active ? 'active' : undefined } />`. This is far from a complete answer and without knowing your current code it may not be very relevant (might need to refactor if using class components). But it is a starting point that might help you out.

Comment: Check this exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438496/remove-a-class-clicking-a-button-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

This basic example should work if you just want to toggle class active:

```
const yourFunction = () => {
   const [isActive, setActive] = useState("");
   
   const toggleActive = () => {
      if (isActive != "")
         setActive("active")
      else setActive("")
   }
   
   return(
   <div className={`other classes go here ${isActive}`}>
   
   </div>

   ...
   
   <button onClick={toggleActive}>Your Button Text</button>
   )

}
```

Comment: Generally, one uses the `is` prefix to specify a boolean, and our state here is in fact a boolean condition, so I'd be inclined to make `isActive` a boolean, and use a ternary to get the class name string.
You can also make `toggleActive = () => {setState(!isActive);}`